# Getting null in response while trying to fetch API response of list type

Tags: java, api, rest

I have a similar response from API as list of objects which is displayed below:

```json
[
  {
    "idGear": "1",
    "name": "lala",
    "year": 2000,
    "price": 15.0
  }, {
    "idGear": "2",
    "name": "lala2",
    "year": 2000,
    "price": 125.0
  }
]
```

I am always getting null in response and unable to parse this. I have tried the following code:

```java
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://abc.def.in/ghij";
Response response = given().header("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token)
          .queryParam("tabId","live_tender") .header("Accept",
          "application/json, text/plain, *").header("Accept-Encoding",
          "gzip, deflate, br") .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8")
          .header("User-Agent",
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
          ) .header("Host", "abc.def.in")

          .log().all().when().post("rest/quotation/showTenderListForBidder").then().
          extract().response();
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: `curl --location --request POST 'https://abc.def.in/ghij/rest/quotation/showTenderListForBidder?tabId=live_tender' \
--header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, *' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
--header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8' \
--header 'User-Agent: <<user-agent details>>' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <<bearer token>>' `
The above curl should mimic what you have tried with the rest assured code snippet - I would check if you get a proper response from a curl or HTTP tool like postman

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Andreas. I have checked this on postman and I can get the response successfully. But I am facing challenges in fetching the response through the code mentioned above! Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!